# `pip` installed `discord.py` to `1.3.4` successfully, but `print(discord.__version__)` displays `1.3.3`

Tags: python, discord.py

I ran the command `pip install discord.py==1.3.4` successfully. However when I ran `print(discord.__version__)` in PyCharm it displayed `1.3.3`. My `pip` version is `20.1.1` and Python is version `3.7`. Does anyone have any idea why the version number is different?

Comment: What is the result when you run in the command line `pip show discord.py`?

Comment: Version: 1.3.4  Location: appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages

Comment: And then when you import discord, where does `discord.__file__` say you're importing discord from? If these two are different, as I suspect they are, then I reckon this is a PYTHONPATH issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not using virtual environment. You may have installed the latest version to your system packages. Be sure to also install it in your dev environment.